# Google Maps does not work

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on an Android 2.2 project. The project needs to display Google Map for user. I select the build target is Android 2.2 and Google Maps classes don't includes in it. How do I solve this problem?

I got

```
[2011-05-11 10:52:54 - Chapter 8 Where Am I 5] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2011-05-11 10:52:54 - Chapter 8 Where Am I 5] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2011-05-11 10:52:54 - Chapter 8 Where Am I 5] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.paad.whereami' in a shell.
[2011-05-11 10:52:54 - Chapter 8 Where Am I 5] Launch canceled!
```

when I try to run tutorial on Google Maps on Google APIs for 3.0

Comment: Did you try working your app in google api 2.2 instead of AVD 2.2

Comment: have you actually done what the message asks you to do?

Comment: Down vote for a terrible question title.. clearly Google Maps does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Google API 2.2 .

For uninstalling the application from the command line, either add the android-sdk path in you $PATH variable or go to the platform-tools folder in the android sdk installation. from thee give this command.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Google API 2.2 or for that matter any but it should be google API as the target.

Comment: ok what about the other problem in adp how i can uninstall the old project manually ?

Comment: Not sure what the question is but if you need to uninstall the previous application just goto settings->Applications and click on the application to uninstall and uninstall.